# Update iFrame-page/ content of iFrame by click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, refresh

If you've read some of my previous questions you know I had a problem that I solved with iFrames. Anyways, what I would like now is to be able to update the page that the iFrame shows (it's a local page of mine) when I click an update button. How is this possible without updating the page I'm on?

Background info:
I'm on home.php where I have an iFrame. This iFrame shows the page something.php, which is one of my pages. I had to be able to update home.php without waiting for something.php to update, so the solution was to place them in two documents and then include it using iFrames (now home.php can be shown without waiting for something.php). The content of this something.php is dynamic and updates based on other webpages. Let's say the user wants to update the content of this iFrame, or the content doesn't show up. He will then be given an button "update" which will just refresh the something.php page, without refreshing home.php

Can this be done (preferably in PHP, but JavaScript/jQuery is also welcome)?

Comment: This does not concern php. You are trying to redirect or reload iframe through home.php without reloading home.php.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik Ahh, okay. I just thought it would be possible to create an function in PHP that could do that. But if not, then js is the way to go. Thanks for the info ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it with client side scripting.

Something along the lines of:

```
<input type="button" onclick="reLoadIframe();">

reLoadIframe(){
  document.getElementById('iframeYoureTryingToUpdate').contentWindow.location.reload();
}
```

or

```
reLoadIframe(){
  document.getElementById('iframeYoureTryingToUpdate').src =document.getElementById('iframeYoureTryingToUpdate').src`
}
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. I'll try those solutions and get back to you. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the url in loc and this should be enough.

```
var loc = "http://example.com/example.php";
var frameId = "myFrame";
document.getElementById(frameId).src = loc;
```

Comment: I didn't understand that... Could you explain what it means?
Should I have the link to the page thats displayed in the iframe in the variable loc (something.php) and then the id of the frame in frameId, and then that last is just the function that should be run when a button is clicked? In that case I think i got it ;)

Comment: @Alekplay Yes that is all. It will open any valid url present in loc in an iframe with specified frameId